# Running io.js with Express

Tags: javascript, express, io.js

I visited the official io.js site (https://iojs.org/) and installed the 1.0.1 release, Mac version. After I installed this, I went to my terminal window and typed:

```
iojs app.js
```

Which I presume is the way to create a io.js project? I'm trying to create a io.js project using Express. Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrespective of using NodeJS or io.js, the answer should be the same. You're going to start an express application and start it.

Assuming you've installed io.js already, on the command line type:

```
#install a generator for the express
npm install express-generator -g 
application

mkdir my-application-folder
cd my-application-folder

#use the express generator to generate a new application
express  

#now install node_modules from package.json
npm install
```

and once you've got the files, you can start the application with:

```
npm start
```

So this should start the application, irrespective of it being nodeJS or iojs.

However, if you're starting out with Node/io and you're looking to make this your webserver, be aware there are a number of add-ons and setting tweaks which are required before an application is suitable for production. See [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) and [here](https://www.joyent.com/developers/node), for example

Answer (score 2):

If `iojs` is a replacement for Node, then manually [create a new file](https://iojs.org/api/synopsis.html) called `app.js` and put this in it:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

And then *run* it with `iojs app.js`.

It says it's `npm` compatible, so you create a new `package.json` file via `npm init` if you desire.

Comment: @CharlesAnthonyBrowne If express creates `app.js`, then I don't see why not. Why don't you try it?

Comment: Did you install it? `npm install express --save`